# What is the difference between import modx and from modx import *?

Tags: python, module, import

If I were to import some module called modx, how would that be different from saying

```
from modx import *
```

Wouldn't all the contents be imported from each either way? This is in python just to clarify.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you `import somemodule` the contained globals will be available via `somemodule.someglobal`. If you `from somemodule import *` ALL its globals (or those listed in `__all__` if it exists) will be made globals, i.e. you can access them using `someglobal` without the module name in front of it.

Using `from module import *` is discouraged as it clutters the global scope and if you import stuff from multiple modules you are likely to get conflicts and overwrite existing classes/functions.

Answer (score 19):

If `a` defines `a.b` and `a.c`...

```
import a
a.b()
a.c()
```

vs.

```
from a import b
b()
c() # fails because c isn't imported
```

vs.

```
from a import *
b()
c()
```

Note that `from foo import *` is generally frowned upon since:

1. It puts things into the global namespace without giving you fine control
2. It can cause collisions, *due* to everything being in the global namespace
3. It makes it unclear what is actually defined in the current file, since the list of what it defines can vary depending on what's imported.

Answer (score 0):

Common question with many faq's to answer... here is one: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Essentially to answer your specific question the second form (`from modx import *`) you get only the public items in modx